# opacity of element

Tags: jquery, css, opacity

I'm trying to set opacity of element by jQuery.

```
$('[class*="OtherFeatur"]').load(function(){
                    $(this).fadeTo(500, 0.5);
                });
```

is not working but when I do

```
                $('[class*="OtherFeatur"]').fadeTo(0,0.5);
```

it will be affected. where is problem of first code?
and which one is better ,set opacity by jQuery or CSS?
how can I do it by css ,that all browser can show it?

Comment: What is the element you are trying to fade?  I'm assuming by the use of `load` that it is an image?  Also, `fadeTo` is an animation, not simply a way to set opacity.  Just setting it in css is not the same as animating it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.load()` - *Load data from the server and place the returned HTML into the matched element.*

So this function works for loading data from the another resource to the element you selected.

probably you need page load event:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('[class*="OtherFeatur"]').fadeTo(0,0.5);
});
```

or if you loads some data, specify the source first in the `.load()` method.

```
$('[class*="OtherFeatur"]').load('mysource.html', function(){
                $(this).fadeTo(500, 0.5);
            });
```

in this case function will be invoked after loading the content.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to just set the `opacity` of element then use `css` method.

```
 $('[class*="OtherFeatur"]').css("opacity", 0.5);
```

Answer (score 2):

An animation need to be longer then 0ms

you can just use:

```
$('[class*="OtherFeatur"]').css({ opacity: 0.5 });
```

if Im not mistaking jquery has extended the opacity rule on the CSS so it applies on all browsers.

Comment: I read it http://www.quirksmode.org/css/opacity.html ,I'm searching for way that work on all browser such as IE

Comment: its doing its magic for all browsers, so IE will change opacity also.

Answer (score 1):

what you are looking for is

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $('[class*="OtherFeatur"]').fadeTo(0,0.5);
});
```