# Issue with Opacity in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've issue with Opacity with IE.

I want to set the Opacity for the Image button on PageLoad.

I've writtern the code like this:

```
<img id="imgadd" alt="Add Text" src="/Images/add.png" onload="this.style.opacity=0.5;"/>
```

This Code is working on all the Browsers except IE..any help would be appreciated...

Comment: Take a look at this link,

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7349738/opacity-of-element

Comment: Since you're using jQuery, (you tagged the question as such) - why don't you just let the library take care of it for you? `$('#imgadd').css('opacity', 0);`

Comment: I'm creating the image dynamically using foreach loop...I'm having the issue to catch the id...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use filter for IE

```
  filter: alpha(opacity=50);
```

IE does not support opacity so you have to use filter for IE.

Comment: can i write the code like this,...<img id="imgadd" src="/Images/add.png" onload="filter: alpha(opacity=50);"/>

Comment: add class onload and put this css in that class.

Comment: try this : onload='this.className=demo'      Css:-   .demo {opacity=0.5;filter: alpha(opacity=50); }

Comment: If we use the Demo class, then, it is not supporting in other browsers. So I've used:class="demo" onload="this.style.opacity=0.5;" and it is working..Thanks for the help..

Comment: Sorry, @Harshit:Error: The value of the property 'alpha' is null or undefined, not a Function object

Answer (score 1):

Expanding off of Harshit's answer:

Since you seem to be applying opacity onload, why not use CSS instead? Add a class name to the images (in this case it's called `foreachImages`, but feel free to choose a more appropriate name):

```
.foreachImages {
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=50)"; /* IE 8 */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=50); /* IE 5.5-7 */
    -moz-opacity: 0.5; /* Older Gecko versions */
    opacity: 0.5; /* CSS3 complaint browsers */
}
```